# ESP-WROVER-KIT-VB - seeking code example to write to display

Tags: esp32

Does anyone have a simple "hello world" example of writing text to the display of a ESP-WROVER-KIT-VB ?

My search skills are failing me today.

Comment: maybe this? ... https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/get-started/

Comment: Thanks (+1), but I have been through that, and it does not help. [This page](https://platformio.org/lib/show/372/openag_mhz16) seems helpful for the previous version, but I still get errors: `.pio\libdeps\esp-wrover-kit\WROVER KIT LCD_ID372\src\WROVER_KIT_LCD.h:15:26: fatal error: Adafruit_GFX.h: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/esp32/lcd/) It worked for me; bigly

Comment: [This](https://hackaday.io/project/25974-micropython-esp32-wrover-lcd) looks like it could be useful for Python

Comment: Not sure how this helps as it's for an image, not writing text.